# Sharing intent android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I created a sharing menu in my app which is a "Note" taking app to share the note the user is currently viewing.  I've got the share menu showing up but now my issue is how to display the currently viewed note to whatever intent the user decides to choose (ie messenger, facebook, whatever).

The code I have so far for the sharing intent is:

```
if (id == R.id.share) {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBodyText = "Check it out. Your message goes here";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Shearing Option"));
    return true;
}
```

and I'm using a simple SQLite database.

Code to edit pre-existing note is as follows:

```
private void updateNote(String noteText) {                                            
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                                       
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.NOTE_TEXT, noteText);                                     
    getContentResolver().update(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, noteFilter, null); 
    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.note_updated), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setResult(RESULT_OK);                                                             
}
```

Not quite sure where to go from here, if there are any duplicate questions I apologize.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: assign the data in your note to `shareBodyText`  it will be passed

Comment: post code where you are calling `updateNote` method

Comment: or is there any method to getNote ?

Comment: Just posted the updateNote code @Redman

Comment: post the code where you are calling that method

Comment: @Redman It's in the main post.

Comment: no its no there,   where ever you are calling update note, There will a string as an argument   , make shareBodyText to that argument and its done